# How to run Slimmerjs in a server without opening a browser?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, slimerjs

I have a process done with Slimerjs just to make a screenshot of my app.
Obviously, it needs to be launched from the server but it opens a browser when I run on my own pc.

How should I run it from a server in production?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats could be helpful :

https://github.com/laurentj/slimerjs/issues/80

or this :

http://docs.slimerjs.org/current/installation.html#having-a-headless-slimerjs